# Problems with AES in crypto-js and pycrypto

Tags: javascript, python, base64, aes, pycrypto

I try to implement a communication between

- [crypto-js](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) (a javascript crypto library)
- and [pycrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) (a python crypto library)

On the *python server side* I encrypt a string with an `iv` and a `passphrase` and send the iv with the encrypted text base64 encoded to the *javascript client side*. Then I want to `decrypt` the string with the passphrase the user can enter.

**python - server**

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random

iv = Random.get_random_bytes(16)
key = "1234567812345678"
aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
encrypted_text = base64.b64encode(aes.encrypt("this is a test.."))
iv = base64.b64encode(iv)
# send iv, encrypted_text to client
```

**javascript - client**

```
// <script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/files/2.5.3-crypto-sha1-hmac-pbkdf2-blockmodes-aes.js">
   </script>
// text, and iv is base64encoded from the python script
// key is a string from an <input type='text'>
decrypted = Crypto.AES.decrypt(text, key, {iv: iv, mode: new Crypto.mode.CFB});
```

With this example I get a javascript error

```
Uncaught URIError: URI malformed
```

But this is just one example - I tried every constellation of base64 encodings/decodings I could think of. I also tried to changed the Mode. But these are all random tests and I want to understand what I really have to do.

- What encoding does the crypt-js want?
- Which mode should I chose?
- Is there something I should change on the python server side?
- what is about padding? Could there be the fault?
- any other javascript libraries you can recommend?

thank you very much and kind reagards,
samuirai

Comment: Try URLEncoding your data in Python and then send it to JS Client.. like "urllib.urlencode(data)"..

Comment: If you are still having problem, take a look at https://gist.github.com/marcoslin/8026990.

Answer (score 0):

Before You encode to base64 You must sum iv and encrypted_text:

```
encrypted_text = base64.b64encode(iv + aes.encrypt("this is a test.."))
```

From the official documentation (https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/doc/) :

As an example, encryption can be done as follows:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random

key = b'Sixteen byte key'
iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
msg = iv + cipher.encrypt(b'Attack at dawn')
```